# My pagination current page number is not visible

Tags: html, css

I have problem with styling pagination.
I have that html code:

```
<nav class="mo-pagination mo-pagination-numeric"><span aria-current="page" class="page-numbers current">1</span>
<a class="page-numbers" href="#">2</a>
<a class="next page-numbers" href="#"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a></nav>
```

```css
.mo-pagination.mo-pagination-numeric .current, .mo-pagination .page-numbers.current::before {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(115deg,rgba(215,8,102,1) 0%, rgba(95,70,150,1) 50%, rgba(44,187,238,1) );
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: destination-out;
  mask-composite: exclude;
}

.mo-pagination.mo-pagination-numeric .current, .mo-pagination .page-numbers.current {
  border: none !important;
}

.mo-pagination>a, .mo-pagination>span {
  border: 2px solid #41394e;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<span aria-current="page" class="page-numbers current">1</span>
```

My pagination element have gradient border and it is okey, but pagination number is not visible.
Please help me with this problem.

Comment: probably change  color:#000 in  .mo-pagination>a, .mo-pagination>span or some darker colour, its a good idea to use inspect element to see exactly whats going on. good luck.

Comment: You would be better off posting a functional code example vs a partial code snippet that doesn't actually show the issue you are having. Your html does not match the css..

Comment: I paste more html code

Comment: color don't work, propably elements is hidden after something

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
.mo-pagination.mo-pagination-numeric .current, .mo-pagination .page-numbers.current::before {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(115deg,rgba(215,8,102,1) 0%, rgba(95,70,150,1) 50%, rgba(44,187,238,1) );
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
}

.mo-pagination.mo-pagination-numeric .current, .mo-pagination .page-numbers.current {
  border: none !important;
}

.mo-pagination>span {
  color: #fff;
}

.mo-pagination>a {
  border: none;
  color: #000;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="mo-pagination mo-pagination-numeric">
  <span aria-current="page" class="page-numbers current">1</span>
  <a class="page-numbers" href="#">2</a>
  <a class="next page-numbers" href="#"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: The code is here: http://mazer.cyber.pl/blog/ this dont work .mo-pagination>span {
  color: #fff;
}